# WooCommerce add to card event and Facebook Pixel

Tags: facebook, woocommerce, pixel, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to install Facebook Pixel. I need to run 'AddToCart' event (JavaScript code):

`fbq('track', 'AddToCart');`

when someone add product to the card. Where I can hook this code?

P.S. I know about plugins, but my client wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Realize with jQuery:

```
$('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function() {
    fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
});
```

but not sure it is correct solution.

Comment: no it's not...you will trigger this many times when someone is fast clicking the button many times...